# How do I specify SSIS Package Database Connection Through Package Configurations?

Tags: sql-server-2005, oracle, ssis, database-connection

I have an SQL 2005 SSIS package that takes data from an Oracle DB Table, and transfers it to a SQL Server Table.

I have set up an "Oracle Provider for OLE DB" for the Oracle connection and a "SQL Native Client" for SQL Server Connection.

The Oracle and SQL connections will depend on the development and shipping stage, which are:

- Local environment
- SYS - For integration and System testing
- UAT - For user acceptance testing
- PRE - Mimics the LIVE system for confidence testing
- Live - The live system

In the Connection Manager for Oracle, it expects the following:

- Server Name (which, for example can be DEVSERVER)
- User Name (which, for example, can be devserver_user)
- Password (which, for example, can be devserver_pass)

So, I was wondering how I could parameterise these such that the settings are picked up depending on the server. Ideally this would be a connection string that is stored in the registry (to have commonality with the architecture of other systems in our company).

I have attempted to specify the above settings through Package Configurations. I have also tried specifying the connection string, which would look something like this:

```
Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=DEVSERVER;User ID=devserver_user;Password=devserver_pass;PLSQLRSet=1;OLE DB Services = -2;
```

I have tried this through a registry setting, environment settings, and XML config file. I am mapping these item to the properties on the connection object, but the settings do not seem to hold. I.e. when I open the connection object these settings are not there.

What happens is that when I open the OLE DB source and specify the connection, it fails, because the connection object is not picking up the items in the Package Configurations.

Is there something I am missing, some setting that I have to configure. I guess I'm not sure as to what I'm not seeing anything!

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just worked this out this myself.

This really was a case of [RTFM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM)! The first paragraph on the [MSDN Package Configurations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141682.aspx) page says it all:

> Typically, you create a package set
>   properties on the package objects
>   during package development, and then
>   add the configuration to the package.

Still, I hope this is still of help to other RTFMers!